# vb.net group by then order by then by Linq

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

In this linq query, I pull back all Entities from a table.  I want to group them by one ID, then order those groups by a date if it exists, and the remaining items I want to order by a different column.
Originally, I did not need to group these items, and this is the code I was using:

```
Dim query = From task In Entities.Task
            Select task

query = query.OrderBy(Function(task) task.DueDate).ThenBy(Function(task) task.TaskItemType.SortOrder)
```

However, now I am wanting to group this by task.ItemId, but I am not sure I am using `.GroupBy` correctly.  I have tried using this:

```
query = query.GroupBy(Function(t) t.ItemId).OrderBy(Function(task) task.DueDate).ThenBy(Function(task) task.TaskItemType.SortOrder
```

But the compiler can't determine `task.DueDate` here and the warning

```
Type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage.  Try specifying type arguments explicitly.
```

It might help to note that `task.ItemID` is of type `Nullable(Of Long)` and `task.DueDate` is of type `Nullable(Of Date)`

I think I need something like

```
query.GroupBy(Function(t) t.ItemID).OrderBy(Of ??)
```

My return statement looks like this:

```
Return query.AsEnumerable().Select(Function(task) New Task() With {
    ....
    })
```

I just don't know, and don't understand how this is supposed to work.

Here is some sample data:

```
Task 1
    ItemID = 1
    DueDate = 9/10/15
Task 2
    ItemID = 1
    DueDate = 9/12/15
Task 3
    ItemID = 2
    DueDate = 9/11/15
```

In this scenario, I would want the group of `(Task 1, Task2)` to be ordered before `Task 3`

Comment: So `DueDate` is a `Nullable(Of Date)`? What is the desired result at all?

Comment: yes, it is also nullable

Comment: What's the desired result? Do you want to select the groups or do you want to flatten them at the end?

Comment: see update for Return statement, everything that makes it to the `groupby/orderby` should be returned as a single `IEnumerable`

Comment: But how do you want to flatten the groups to task-objects. Do you want to remove duplicates or do you want to order the groups by `DueDate`+`SortOrder` and the groups themselves by the `ItemID`? Without sample data it's difficult to understand.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter Ultimately, I would want my tasks to be grouped by `ItemID`, and then ordered by `DueDate` using the earliest date in the group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `GroupBy` the result is not a sequence of your original task-object but groups of tasks. That's why you can't access properties of them. The groups are a sequence, so multiple.

If you want to flatten the groups to an ordered sequence of tasks you use `SelectMany`:

```
query = query.
    GroupBy(Function(t) t.ItemId).
    SelectMany(Function(group) group.
        OrderBy(Function(task) task.DueDate).ThenBy(Function(task) task.TaskItemType.SortOrder))
```

Comment: I added some test data above -- this throws no errors, I am not entirely sure it is working as expected.  Testing now